# Construct a RDD[Edge[ED]] from RDD[Long, Long, ED] in GraphX

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, spark-graphx

I am now trying to construct a `RDD[Edge[String]]` from `RDD[(Long,Long,String)]`
I have seen the src code of `Edge`, it has parameter of `Edge(VertexId,VertexId,ED)`, So I think if I have a `RDD[(Long,Long,String)]` I can transform it into `RDD[Edge[String]]`

My code is

```
val c:RDD[(String, String)] = something
val s:RDD[(String, String)] = something
val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[String]] = c
        .join(s).map({
            case (num: String, (src: String, dst: String)) 
                => (src.toLong, dst.toLong, expRelation)
        }
    )
```

But finally I got a `type mismatch` error

```
[error]  found   : (Long, Long, String)
[error]  required: org.apache.spark.graphx.Edge[String]
[error]                     => (src.toLong, dst.toLong, expRelation)
[error]                        ^
```

So I wonder if there is a way to construct a `RDD[Edge[ED]]` directly from `RDD[(Long,Long,ED)]`

Comment: `Edge(src.toLong, dst.toLong, expRelation)`

Comment: @user9613318 Wow! It seems works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is not returning Edge[String]. Change return type to

`Edge(src.toLong, dst.toLong, expRelation)`

Code:

```
val c:RDD[(String, String)] = something
val s:RDD[(String, String)] = something
val edgeRDD: RDD[Edge[String]] = c
        .join(s).map({
            case (num: String, (src: String, dst: String)) 
                => Edge(src.toLong, dst.toLong, expRelation)
        }
    )
```